# which AVL trees have a node which deleting him cause an OMEGA(LOGn) rotation to re balance

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, computer-science, avl-tree

i need to find an Infinite set of AVL trees
which have an node X
so when u delete this node
its cause a OMEGA(log(n)) of rotation to re balance while n is the number of nodes